# Netbeans save hangs

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I have a Editor TopComponent implemented. For some reason when I save a document, it throws an error. Listed below is the error. I am not sure where to start with this exception. Would you be able to share what you know ? Thanks

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-causation not permitted 
   at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:458) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.MutualExclusionSupport.addStack(MutualExclusionSupport.java:122) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.MutualExclusionSupport.addStack(MutualExclusionSupport.java:109) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.MutualExclusionSupport.addResource(MutualExclusionSupport.java:98) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FileObj.getOutputStream(FileObj.java:127) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FileObj.getOutputStream(FileObj.java:102) 
   at org.openide.text.DataEditorSupport$Env.outputStream(DataEditorSupport.java:891) 
   at org.openide.text.CloneableEditorSupport.saveDocument(CloneableEditorSupport.java:1172) 
   at org.openide.text.DataEditorSupport.superSaveDoc(DataEditorSupport.java:602) 
   at org.openide.text.DataEditorSupport$SaveImpl.run(DataEditorSupport.java:1315) 
   at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:127) 
   at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:609) 
   at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(FileUtil.java:415) 
   at org.openide.text.DataEditorSupport.saveDocument(DataEditorSupport.java:598) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.openide.loaders.SimpleES$SaveCookieImpl.save(SimpleES.java:226) 
   at org.openide.actions.SaveAction.performAction(SaveAction.java:132) 
   at org.openide.actions.SaveAction.performAction(SaveAction.java:102) 
   at org.openide.actions.SaveAction$Delegate.actionPerformed(SaveAction.java:249) 
   at org.openide.awt.ContextAction$Performer.actionPerformed(ContextAction.java:231) 
   at org.openide.awt.ContextManager.actionPerformed(ContextManager.java:257) 
   at org.openide.awt.ContextAction.actionPerformed(ContextAction.java:109) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:93) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$ActionRunnable.actionPerformed(ActionInvoker.java:162) 
   at org.netbeans.core.ModuleActions.invokeAction(ModuleActions.java:109) 
   at org.netbeans.modules.openide.actions.ActionsBridgeImpl.invokeAction(ActionsBridgeImpl.java:60) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$ActionRunnable.doRun(ActionInvoker.java:153) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$2.run(ActionInvoker.java:110) 
   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432) 
   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044) 
Caused: org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$SlowItem: task failed due to 
   at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor.post(RequestProcessor.java:424) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:114) 
   at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:99) 
   at org.openide.awt.GeneralAction$BaseDelAction.actionPerformed(GeneralAction.java:234) 
   at org.openide.windows.TopComponent.processKeyBinding(TopComponent.java:1176) 
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2940) 
   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842) 
   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282) 
   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229) 
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861) 
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287) 
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687) 
   at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895) 
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762) 
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027) 
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899) 
   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727) 
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731) 
   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287) 
   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719) 
   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680) 
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) 
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694) 
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) 
   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693) 
   at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159) 
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242) 
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161) 
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150) 
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146) 
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138) 
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**EDIT 1**

I have a dataObject and a VisualElement subclasses which have a new mime-type `text/x-puml` configured. Once I changed these back to `text/plain` things started working. I searched for `text/plain` to see if I missed changing anything to `text/x-puml`, I couldn't find any. Is there any other things I should change to change the mime type to `text/x-puml`?

**EDIT 2**

Seems to happen sporadically now, but happens more often than not. Do I need to implement my own SaveCookie or Savable if I have a custom mime-type ?

Comment: Which line in the stacktrace contains a class that you wrote or edited?

Comment: That's the part that is funny, there isn't a line referring to my code. But I did find just now what is causing the issue. I had a new mime-type registered `text/x-puml`, once I changed this to `text/plain` the problem vanished. Would you happen to know if I am missing any configuration.

Comment: I haven't played with custom MIME types in NetBeans, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

it looks for me like a semaphore problem.

The System can't save the file because there is an exclusive lock on this file. another exclusive lock (as needed for saving) is not possible.

Try to look at the file handling. Somewhere must be a lock.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error due to renaming, and it was because of the file´s lock. So i used the file´s lock with `primaryFile.lock()` in:

```
WindowManager.getDefault().invokeWhenUIReady(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (obj.getDomainModel() != null)
        {
            String newName = obj.getDomainModel().getName();
            FileObject primaryFile = obj.getPrimaryFile();
            try
            {
                primaryFile.rename(primaryFile.lock(), newName, primaryFile.getExt());
                callback.updateTitle(newName);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                String message = String.format("The model couldn´t be renamed to \"%s\"", newName);

                LOG.warning(message);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Use it for saving the file or any case alike.

Comment: I my example i had the same problem but for renaming instead of saving. But its the same issue: the lock of a file previously opened.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misread your answer pretty badly. Removed the downvote, thanks for clarifying